# Outlook 2010 not launching when I debug my Outlook addin?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, outlook

I'm totally confused as to how to debug an Outlook 2010 addin I'm trying to develop.  I created a new `Extensibility | Shared Add-in` project and just checked Outlook, and it's created a new project for me with a stub implementation of the Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2 interface in my `Connect.cs` file.  However, when I press F5 to debug, although the project compiles OK, a new instance of Visual Studio opens up instead of Microsoft Outlook!  How am I supposed to debug my addin?

Comment: Attach the debugger to outlook.

Comment: Well, 1) How can I debug code in events like `OnConnection` which will happen before I manage to attach the debugger?  and 2) Why does it start a new instance of Visual Studio on debug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Outlook is the host process that will load your code you have to make sure that Outlook is the target application for debugging (go to project properties and select the main Outlook EXE under the Start external program option in the Debug settings).
Then of course you have to also make sure that your plugin is actually being loaded by Outlook. With that in place you should be able to debug your plug-in with VS.

Comment: Aha, that did it!  Well, it's not actually called a "Debug target", it's the value for the "Start external program" setting in the Debug settings.  When I changed that to the Outlook exe I could start debugging my addin.